# Copy permissions from one Windows Folder to another

Tags: c#, winforms, security, permissions, copy

I need to create a small C# Windows app which copies security permissions from one folder to another. That includes copying group permissions too. What would be the best way to approach such a challenge?

Yosief Kesete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get out the folder with [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) then get out an instance of the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) class using the [GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol.aspx) method. 
Then you'll be able to call [GetAccessRules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.getaccessrules.aspx) and [AddAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.addaccessrule.aspx) which should hopefully get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing the whole thing yourself, why don't you get your app to run a tool like [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) (use the `-l` parameter), and then apply permissions to the target folder based on the info you parse from the output of AccessChk.