# copying folders and preserving permissions

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Guys ive been tasked with creating an app that will create a bunch of folders with permissions on our network in a share specified by the user.  My thoughts are to create the folders as a template with all the necessary permission and then the app will simply copy the template to the specified share.  Is it possible to in C# or powershell to copy the folders and preserve the permissions when doing so.  Ive done a google search but cant find anything conclusive.

Comment: some hints using powershell: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/05/11/copy-acl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There you go, simple use the class FileSecurity to transfer permissions of files.

[Google first result on c# copy files maintain permissions](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/1dc00f8c-b338-4760-aecb-024fe5009ed6.aspx)

And Directory Security for the folders:

[Directory Security 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323390/copy-permissions-from-one-windows-folder-to-another)

[Directory Security 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx)

Comment: thanks, im not looking to copy files as the question states its only folders.  With regards the Directory 1 link i did see that but the question isnt marked as answered, it hasnt even been up voted.  Thanks for the response though

Comment: Also the answer is given by @ho1 not exactly a newbie ^^
In any case the Directory Security works, regarding answers i typed it to give you an answer not because of credit.

Comment: i just checked and your right it is very low, however that still doesnt mean thats the correct answer.  its been viewed 501 times and has not had any votes.  Makes me think that maybe that isnt a good way of doing it.  Ill run some test code to have a look though.

Comment: just check link Directory Security 2 and use that sample.
Microsoft sometimes makes mistakes but not this severe on their own productS ^^