# How to handle Orphaned NTFS Permissions when reading Source Permissions

Tags: c#, acl, ntfs

I followed information in this thread [C# Copying a Folder to another destination with Security/Permission Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533767/)

I've managed to get my app to copy files and folders with permissions, but it totally clocks out when it hits any folders with Orphaned Permissions.

Permissions like S-1-5-21-236079...…

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So this was my solution, checked in the loop for "S-1-5" and skipped it.

```
    private void PermissionGet(DirectoryInfo Source, DirectoryInfo Destination)
    {
        string Username;
        DirectorySecurity SourceSecurity = Source.GetAccessControl();

        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule Rules in SourceSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
        {
            Username = Rules.IdentityReference.Value;
            if (!Username.Contains("S-1-5"))
            {
                PermissionSet(Username, Rules.FileSystemRights, Rules.AccessControlType, Destination);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PermissionSet(string Username, FileSystemRights Permission, AccessControlType Access, DirectoryInfo Destination)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectorySecurity Security = Destination.GetAccessControl();
            Security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Username, Permission, Access));
            Destination.SetAccessControl(Security);
        }
        
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```